# 'The executable was signed with invalid entitlements' on iPad, works fine on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, code-signing

I've been running my app on my iPhone just fine, and then i plug it into my iPad to run it on there, to test iCloud, and it gives me the code signing error `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements`.

Any ideas why this might be? The idea of going through my certificates and profiles and re-doing them doesn't really appeal to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar error before and my fix was to open the organizer (window -> organizer in 4.2) and click on the device and then select "Use this device for development".

[image]

Also, ensure that the second device has all the correct provisioning information in the Organizer as the first device that worked.

Edit 1:

Another thing I just thought of:

Make sure that you set it to deploy for Iphone and Ipad:

Under target edit the settings that look like this - [image]

Edit 2:

Also, check the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) for Apple and make sure you add your device to the list of devices for that provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

It is not stated if you already did this, but you need to make sure that you register the UUID of your iPad with Apple and it can be done in the iOS developer center.  If this is not already done, (unfortunately) you'll also need to create a new provisioning profile and use that to compile the App and add it to both devices.